# create open email tracker for mail native app

Tags: php, email, tracking, email-analytics

I am creating a tracker by PHP to get percent of opened email.

My code worked well if user open email by browser , but if user open email by an application (Mailbox for example) I can't detect it.

I don't know why but when I tried to saw log file, I saw that browser can requested to my server but native app can't.

```
<img src="Domain.tracker" width="1" height="1" style="display: none"/>
```

ANSWER:
When user open email by Application, you have to provide protocol to access your track server

```
<img src="http://Domain.tracker" width="1" height="1" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: Some mail clients don't show images by default or filter those pixels out of the email content. Especially when you're hiding it. A transparent pixel would also work here. Just to be sure, you do use an url instead of "Domain.tracker" as the src, right?

Comment: Btw, I would suggest to take a look at existing solutions for this. There are companies with e-mail tracking and delivery as their core business. Some even for free, like http://mandrill.com/

Comment: i tested by open email by browser, it will work well, i got record. but when open by application (both mac mail and iphone mail) i couldnot get any request to my tracker

Comment: Yes, you said that. Some mail clients/applications don't show images by default or filter those tracking pixels out of the email content. Especially when you're hiding it.

Comment: <img src="Domain.tracker" width="1" height="1"/>
this tag didnt work too, ofcause Domain.tracker is my tracker link and it return image/gif 1x1